# Are there attempts to develop a more accessible sed?

Tags: sed, accessibility

`sed` pseudocode:

```bsh
sed
    "FROM"
        $to = ".*";$
    "TO"
        $to = "'"$new_email_address"'";
    "GLOBAL"
FILE_PATH
```

- Mere line breaks are allowed
- Tab indentation is allowed
- There is no necessity to use single line segmentation
- There is no necessity to wrap commands in quote marks as with `sed "/s/X/Y/g" FILE`
- Using a data structure such as `"'"$new_email_address"'"` in the above example would be easier because it won't be situated inside a dense long line which is already quote marked; furthermore, the wrapping could be done with some new character just for strings that include variable expansion in them (`STRING_WITH_VARIABLEEXPANSION data STRING_WITH_VARIABLEEXPANSION`) instead mixing quote marks

I would be happy to work with such a `sed`, because I find it more accessible and ordinal than the regular syntax, hence the question in title.

Answer (score 1):

I know of one attempt to develop a more accessible `sed`. However, it does not exactly what you want.

## [sd](https://github.com/chmln/sd)

Intuitive find & replace CLI (`sed` alternative) in `rust`.

It is limited in functionalities (compared to `sed`) and certainly have flaws originating from its simplicity. You better learn more about `sed` and other utilities if you want superpowers. I've tested `sd` under Fedora 34 (works with `dnf install sd`)  and Ubuntu 21.04 (with Ubuntu I've installed cargo and a dependency : `build-essential`).

---

Replace newlines with commas:

```
sd: sd '\n' ',' input.txt
sed: sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' input.txt
```

`sd` syntax in this case is the same as `tr`.

```
tr '\n' ',' < input.txt
```

---

In place modification of files:

```
sd: sd before after file.txt
sd: sd 'before this' 'after that' file.txt
sed -i 's/before/after/g' file.txt
```

---

Extracting stuff out of strings containing slashes:

```
# Strings between () are groups.

echo "sample with /path/" | sd '.*(/.*/)' '$1'
/path/

echo "sample with /path/" | sd '(.*)/.*/' '$1'
sample with

# Capture two groups and invert.
echo "sample with /path/" | sd '(.*)(/.*/)' '$2$1'
/path/sample with
```

---

```
echo 'lots((([]))) of special chars' | sd -s '((([])))' ''
lots of special chars
    -s, --string-mode
            Treat expressions as non-regex strings
```

Multiline replacement :

```
sd 'test\nmultiline' 'this\ntest'  input.txt
```

Another option :

```
-p, --preview
  Output result into stdout and do not modify files
```

There is also an attempt for a more simpler `find` (developed in `rust` too) :
[fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd).

Comment: Hello, I have suggested a minor edit to the answer but it was rejected; I don't know if you had a chance to review it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/388860